# How to know the external ip address of my gateway?

Tags: networking, router, local-area-network

In my office network I unknowingly changed the setting of my gateway of lan network .. I had set my phone's ip address under a section in settings which states that.. Only this ip can login to the network.. And the ip which i filled in was of my phone which is connected to my office wifi network.. Due to this reason none of the computers in the lan network can access the router's login page.. I had used the gui interface.. So now I need to know my lan's router external ip address.. So that i can access the router login page on my phone

Comment: https://icanhazip.com/ will display this.

Comment: If the ip you authorized was of your phone while your phone was connected to your wireless network then you ought to be able to look at your DHCP server and determine what that address is/was. Then temporarily assign that ip address to your computer and use it to log in to your router and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can just visit https://www.whatismyip.com/ and the site will tell you what your external IP address is.

Regards

-- arl

Answer (score 0):

Connect an Ethernet cable directly to your router, If the router is set to use DHCP, wait to get an IP on your computer, then open CMD and type ipconfig You will see the IP, Subnet and Default Gateway IP

If you router is not using DHCP, assign the same IP range to your NIC (Same IP as your Phone  Ex. If your phone is using 192.168.1.27, assign 192.168.1.200 to your NIC manually) and connect directly to your router using an Ethernet cable, then open CMD and type ipconfig You will see the IP, Subnet and Default Gateway IP. Make sure is using the same as your phone.

You will able to login to the router and make the necessary changes to fix the issue.